# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class when call StartActivity()

Tags: android

From my Package A class, I try to Start Activity in Package B.

It works ok, when I try this way:

```
new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ClassB.class);
```

However, when try to create `Intent` via this way:

```
ComponentName componentName = ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.example.package/.ClassB");
```

It gives error: `**android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:** Unable to find explicit activity class {};` have you declared this activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`? My problem is need to call it 2nd way only via `ComponentName`.

Though I have referred to all relevant loops for this question, didn't found solution. Also I have declared ok in my manifest like below (otherwise I suppose it would not have been called via 1st method):

```
<activity android:name="com.example.package.ClassB"
    android:exported="true"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true" />
```

Please check if possible to help ? Also both package are part of same App.

Comment: are you sure that package name is "com.example.package" didn't you change it in gradle  for given variant?

Comment: Can you try: ComponentName.createRelative("com.example.package", "ClassB");

Comment: @Selvin yes, double ensured that..

Comment: @X3Btel isn't it the same as appending**/.** to the ClassName

Comment: Yes it is the same- I was trying to debug your issues, as it was supposed to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything you wrote in your question is correct, then the application ID of your app is not `com.example.package`. So, change:

```
ComponentName componentName = ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.example.package/.ClassB");
```

to:

```
ComponentName componentName = ComponentName.unflattenFromString("xxx/com.example.package.ClassB");
```

where `xxx` is the application ID of your app. In particular, the right-hand side of the component name should be the `android:name` value for the `<activity>` in the manifest, and the left-hand side should be the application ID of the app. You can always call `getComponentName()` on an activity to find out its `ComponentName` (e.g., to log to LogCat to see what it looks like).

Then, reconsider doing any of this. While you write that you "need to call it 2nd way only via ComponentName", I cannot think of any scenario where `ComponentName` would be a requirement.

For example, suppose that you are saving the string representation of the `ComponentName` in a file. That is risky, as it means that you can never refactor your app, as otherwise your saved `ComponentName` values will become invalid. Instead, save something in the file that represents a logical activity, and have application code that maps that value to the proper Java class to use in an explicit `Intent`.

Comment: Works perfect..Thanks CommonsWare for your help. However I am bit confused by description on Developer site or am I missing something:     flattenToString

added in API level 1
String flattenToString ()
Return a String that unambiguously describes both the package and class names contained in the ComponentName. You can later recover the ComponentName from this string through unflattenFromString(String).
Returns
String Returns a new String holding the package and class names. This is represented as the **package name**,concatenated with a '/' and then the class name.No App Id is mention?

Comment: @SahilMehta Application ID in android is usually the package name- In the test case `com.example.package`

Comment: @X3Btel yes, but as per my case turned out, it can be different as well, so may be specifying Application ID could make things more clear.

Comment: @SahilMehta: The change in nomenclature from "package name" to "application ID" happened part-way through Android's life, and the documentation is unlikely to ever catch up.